# Use ExUnit.Assertions inside macro

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

I have written a small macro for test cases.

```
    defmodule ControllerTest do
      @required [:phone, :country]
      defmacro create(fields) do
        quote do
          without = length(unquote(@required) -- unquote(field)
          if without != 0 do
            Enum.map(unquote(@required), fn(field) ->
              member = Enum.member?(unquote(fields), field)
              if member == false do
                expected_error = String.to_atom(Atom.to_string(field) <> " " <> "can't be blank")
                expected = {:error, expected_error}
               assert expected == {:error, expected_error} 
              end
            end)
          else
            expect = {:success, "Record created"}
            assert expect == {:success, "Record created"}
          end
        end
      end
     end
```

Its working fine without assert. But when I try to use assert it says assert is undefined. I have try `import ExUnit.Assertions` inside the module but still the same `assert` is undefined.

What will be the possible solution for this to use assert inside the macro?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you add that `import`? Try adding it after `quote do` and before `without =`.

Comment: @Dogbert I was adding it before quote. It works. Thanks.Post it as an answer. I will mark it accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `import` inside the `quote` before you use `assert`. Adding it before `quote` will not make `assert` available inside `quote`.

```
defmacro create(fields) do
  quote do
    import ExUnit.Assertions
    without = ...
    ...
  end
end
```

---

Also, your `Enum.map` can be simplified like this:

```
for field <- unquote(@required), field not in unquote(fields) do
  expected_error = String.to_atom(Atom.to_string(field) <> " " <> "can't be blank")
  expected = {:error, expected_error}
  assert expected == {:error, expected_error} 
end
```